# Comparing two dates with VBA CountIfs

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sets of dates (yyyy/mm/dd) in two columns, I want to check if the dates are the same or not.  I tried the following line of code and it doesn't seem to work

```
If (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(completed.Columns(2), "=", row.Columns(5))) Then
```

Is it possible to compare two sets of dates with CountIfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible to count the number of matching dates. but the countifs format should be followed correctly. May be you need some thing like below. please check your other code accordingly.

```
If (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range(completed.Columns(2)),row.Columns(5).value) = row.Columns(5)) Then
```

Format to use CountIfs

```
CountIfs(Range to check as range, Argument as value)
```

Comment: alternatively, why cant you use just a comparison of values? any limitation?

Comment: do you get an error for correct format of Countifs or you tried to compare the values? If you were trying to compare values, share your code to verify.